# if no file upload, file id in database should be: placeholder.gif

Tags: php, mysql, image, postgresql, upload

i have a form where you can put an image uploade, which is optional. with this script at the moment it writes upload/timestamp into my database. but i need to replace that with a placeholder if no file is uploaded. here is the code:

```
    $allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 1024000)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
  {
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
    }
  else
    {
      $path_parts = pathinfo($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      "upload/" . $path_parts['filename'].'_'.time().'.'.$path_parts['extension']);
      }
    }
else
  {
  echo "Invalid file";
  }
```

and:

```
$name1 = $_REQUEST['name1'];
$email1 = $_REQUEST['email1']; 
$beschreibung1 = $_REQUEST['beschreibung1'] ;
$latitude = $_REQUEST['latitude'] ;
$longitude = $_REQUEST['longitude'] ;
$file = $_REQUEST['file'] ;
$pic = ("upload/" . $path_parts['filename'].'_'.time().'.'.$path_parts['extension']);

include 'bikemap_db_open.php';

$sql = "INSERT INTO input2 (f_name, f_e_mail, f_text, f_adr, f_dat, f_geom, f_foto)"; 
$sql = $sql . " VALUES ('" . $name1 . "','" . $email1 . "','" . $beschreibung1 .  
       "','" . $longitude . " " . $latitude . "', '" . date("d-m-Y") . "',      ST_GeomFromText('POINT(" . $longitude . " " . $latitude . ")', 4326),'" . $pic . "')"; 

$result = pg_query($sql) or die('Query failed: ' . pg_last_error());

include 'bikemap_db_close.php';

header( "Location: /danke.html" );exit;
```

Comment: just check that the length of the filename is > 0 if it is then do upload and use filename on insert if not then don't do upload and just use a static string to placeholder.gif or whatever

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first code block

```
else
  {
  echo "Invalid file";
  $fileupload = false;
  }
```

In second codeblock

```
if ($fileupload == true){
$pic = ("upload/" . $path_parts['filename'].'_'.time().'.'.$path_parts['extension']);
}
else
{
$pic = 'placeholder.gif'; // you will need to specify the full path
}
```